# OpenCV Python GTK Error

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, gtk

I am having trouble installing getting opencv to work with Python on Ubuntu.  I am getting the following error:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

when trying to run the following command:

```
cv2.imshow('test', rand(20,20))
```

I have the canberra module installed for both GTK and GTK 3:

```
locate libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your Python version 64-bit as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058926/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-unable-to-connect-to-db)

Answer (score 0):

That message is usually harmless, since modules are optional to GTK's functionality; is `cv2.imshow()` not working because of it?

GTK's module path usually defaults to `/usr/lib/gtk-3.0` (or 2.0 depending on which version of GTK you are linking to) or `/usr/lib64/gtk-3.0`. Try running your program with the environment variable `GTK_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0` (or 2.0).

Comment: could you tell me how to solve or debug this warning. I've installed gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 with the first version it works fine, but not with the second. I installed OpenCV from source.