# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text

Tags: gtk, sublimetext, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on a remote server (Ubuntu 14.04) through SSH -X. I have installed Sublime Text and when I try to open it I get

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Unable to connect to dbus
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

> sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*

if you run that install it will get 120+ mb of libs, mostly.  to get rid of that module error, you only need to install 70k.  i fixed the same error with this single package:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

that should do the trick.  if that doesnt work try installing only the canberra libs, you don't need all those Xlibs, or you'd have them already ;) 
here's **just** canberra packages apt listed:

*libcanberra-gtk-common-dev libcanberra-gtk-dev libcanberra-gtk-module
  libcanberra-gtk-module-dbg libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk0-dbg
  libcanberra-gtk3-0-dbg libcanberra-gtk3-dev libcanberra-gtk3-module-dbg
  libcanberra-dev*

10 total packages, instead of over 100 packages with that * wildcard. save space, boot time, sys speed etc, always, if you can :)

Answer (score 3):

As I found at the end of this [thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-936168/), it appears to be a problem with the libcanberra dependencies, I stumbled upon this and the solution worked for me on Sublime Text 2/Debian 8.
So try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk*
```

This got rid of the GTK message, but the "Unable to connect to dbus..." stuff disappeared when I executed sublime as a non-root user.

Answer (score -1):

On Debian Stretch:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

This will install:

> The following additional packages will be installed:
>     libcanberra-gtk0
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk0