# Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar", "unity-gtk-module", "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: python, gtk

Whenever I try to plot a graph in python (using matplotlib library) or show an image (using matplotlib/opencv library) in my Ubuntu 14.04 terminal, i get this GTK-Message (Sometimes even if the code is running fine and plotting the image:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
init done 
opengl support available
```

I tried to download the above modules and tried solving this problem, but was not successful.

Please note that I am not looking for an alternative (like using some other library). It would be great if someone could explain why this problem occurs and how I can solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" Unable to connect to dbus - Sublime text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058926/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-unable-to-connect-to-db)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I will say that these are not bugs in your program.

Comment: @ptomato yes, error is same but i still can't get rid of the problem

Comment: @andlabs yes, but i am not able to execute my programs because of these

Comment: You said the errors occur even if the code is running fine. How are you not able to execute your programs?

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? I am also stuck with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to run

```
conda clean --all
```

This seems to fix all the references.